# Does XAMPP support SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I want to connect php to SQL Server in my xampp server. When I use the code `mssql_connect` it is giving me an error. Please find any solution and let me know whether xampp supports php connecting to SQL Server.

Comment: What code are you using, and what error are you seeing?

Comment: what error you get when you run your code?

Comment: xampp is more geared to supporting mysql/apache/php. most likely mssql support is not enabled by default, and/or not included with the package.

Answer (score 4):

`mssql`-support isn't enabled by default in xampp. to enable it you'll have to open your `xampp/php/php.ini` and remove the semi-colon before the following line (down at the "Dynamic Extensions"-category):

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll // just if you want to use PDO
```

after doing that, restart apache and you're done.

Comment: I'm from the future (2019). Has this changed? I don't see ```extension=php_mssql.dll``` but there is an entire [MSSQL] section around line 1966 (last section of the file)

Answer (score 1):

yes it will support.

but you have to make some changes in xampp database server

delete semicolon in front